# AngularJS don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I had watched an tutorial about AngularJS. In this tutorial was showed how to build an easy hello world app but when I try the exactly same code it dosen't work.

All scripts are loaded well. Has someone an idea?

**index.html**

```
<!DOTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    /* load angular and controller script */
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyFirstCtrl">{{test}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
function MyFirstCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = "Hello World";
}
```

My output is {{test}}.

Comment: You need to put the name of your app inside `ng-app`

Comment: initialize your app using ngapp directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give name to your [ng-app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive, a different way using [Controller as](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) syntax, would be:

```
<!DOTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    /* load angular and controller script */
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyFirstCtrl as myFirst">{{myFirst.test}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and controller js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('MyFirstCtrl', function () {
  this.test = 'Some test';
});
```

A [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wqcxvLw3/)

Answer (score -1):

You must create the app like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyFirstController',['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = "Hello World";
}]);
```

And load in html ngApp the respective app:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the `angular` script and your `controller` script

```
<!DOTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/controller.js"></script>
  </head>
...
```